# How can I use dynamic CSV Data with Echarts & ds3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, charts, echarts

I am new to Javascript (absolute beginner) with basic understanding of HTML and have settled on Echarts to produce some metric charts because

- It costs nothing, opensource.
- has a wealth of charts
- Good documentation
- Produces an HTML file
- Resulting HTML file is self contained, i dont need any other software to make it work
- I am however still open to better suggestions

The issue i am having is that I want to use CSV to input data, the Echarts documentation is almost non-existent on this front - and provides only one example which doesnt work for me.
However I have managed to get my data to work with d3s.csv function.

I would like to produce a set of metrics, for approx 20 modules. They are categorised into different levels, phases and modules.  I want to provide HTML buttons to change levels (level 1, 2, 3) which in turn filters out the modules for those levels - e.g.

Level 1 - module1, module1a, module1b
Level 2 - Module2, module2a
Level 3 - Module3a, module3b, module3c, module3d, module3e
Level 4 - module4a

When the user selects each module, i would like the chart to read the CSV data for the corresponding module, and refresh the chart.

The x-axis will display the phase

Currently, I am going to have to use different CSV files for each module - with data looking like this

```
//Phase         Draft   Available   Approved    Authorised  Accepted    Deleted
//Phase 1       14          24          45          29          14       24
//Phase 2       77          18          36          23          77       33
//Phase 3       34          28          17          44          34       73
//Phase 4       45          33          67          81          45       77
//Phase 5       36          73          33          38          36       73
```

My question is - how can I get new CSV data to load and refresh a chart with e-charts, when a user clicks a button? Ideally i would like the ds3.csv to load with a different CSV file, change  a few things like the title, but keep all other settings the same to refresh the chart.

I have this construct

```
    d3.csv("data/Module4a.csv",function(error,csvdata)
    {
        if(error)
        { 
            console.log(error);  
        }
        else
        {
            for( var i=0; i<csvdata.length; i++ )
            {
                xaxis.push               (csvdata[i].Phase);                //x-axis
                Data_P2Draft.push        (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Draft));  
                Data_P2Available.push    (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Available)); 
                Data_P2Approved.push     (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Approved));
                Data_P2Authorised.push   (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Authorised));
                Data_P2Accepted.push     (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Accepted));
                Data_P2Deleted.push      (parseFloat(csvdata[i].Deleted));
            }    

            var option = 
            {
                title: "this is the title"
             // more e-charts options here
            }

            if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
                myChart.setOption(option);
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself - it was as easy as passing the arguments to a higher level function which took athe d3 call - i.e

```
function level5 (title, CSVfile)
{
   d3.csv (CSVfile, function(error, csvdata)
   {
     // stuff
   }
}
```

and then have something like

```
// table def here
<tr> <td id="val1" onclick="level5('new title', 'csv-data-1')"> click here for dataset1 <td></tr>
```